# Failed to download repo vuetifyjs/webpack: Response code 404 (Not Found)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I am trying to install the Vuetify template from [vuetifyjs.com](https://monosnap.com/file/fhIWRsksjOVN5W2h0RQoUTDliFm0V4)

I wrote:

```
vue init vuetifyjs/webpack ad-project
```

[It replied with](https://monosnap.com/file/OsnhuF6k3UoFZeuEFOqxoTaEb42W5i):

> ```
> vue-cli · Failed to download repo vuetifyjs/webpack: Response code 404 (Not Found)
> ```

What do I do? Where I can find it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Webpack template was previously located in Vuetify's GitHub repo. However, they recently updated their templates to use Vue CLI 3 and as a result, the template you are referencing was removed. It is recommended to upgrade to the new version of the Vue CLI before starting a project:

```
npm uninstall vue-cli -g
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

You can then create a new Vuetify project with:

```
vue create my-app
cd my-app
vue add vuetify
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there are no repositories on GitHub named vuetifyjs/webpack.
Have you followed the getting started guide at [vuetifyjs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#new-applications)?